# Initialising a user control in code behind not working - MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am initialising a user control in code behind as the control ctor takes a MainViewModel as parameter. I also have a default ctor for this to keep XAML happy.

Now, as I understand it- XAML automatically initialises the user control using the default ctor but as I am re-initalising it in code behind - I can see that this is not working as I am getting all sorts of binding errors.

XAML:

```
  <childViews:SomeView x:Name="SomeViewUc"/>
```

XAML.cs:

```
public MainView(IMainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = mainViewModel;
    SomeViewUc = new SomeView(new SomeViewModel(mainViewModel)); 
}
```

Why is the new Initialisation not working? Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that it is good idea to set context of view that way? Most people is doing this through xaml. Also this way your view is dependent on view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace an existing control this way... you need to remove the control from the parent control and add a new one.

But have you tried something like this?

```
public MainView(IMainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = mainViewModel;
    SomeViewUc.DataContext = new SomeViewModel(mainViewModel); 
}
```

You should think about other ways to instantiate the view model, e.g. with a [view model locator](http://www.johnpapa.net/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum/) or directly in XAML. I wrote a [blog article](http://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/) about view model instantiation and other best practices.

Comment: SO, is it OK to set the data context of the UC by binding them to a property in the Main view model. These views are child views and are inside a main view. The Main view model in this case would have a reference to all child view model. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I'd say it is not good practice. I think each view should instantiate its view model itself and a sub view should be parameterized with dependency properties... (have a look at my article)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up creating a Dependency property on the child view which accepts the MainViewModel and view sets it's own datacontext.